# Node.js Firestore authentication issues (while javascript works)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking to anonymously connect to a Firestore and grab some data from a collection. This works perfectly fine under javascript, while it fails ("FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions") under node.js. Any pointers will be appreciated.

This is the code that **works** without a hitch under javascript (I have omited the 'script' includes) and it returns data as expected:

```
var config = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log(error.message);
});

foo();
async function foo() {
  var db=firebase.firestore();
  var query = await db.collection("collection").limit(5).get();
  query.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.data());
  });
}
```

This is the code that does **not** work under node.js. The config/authdata is exactly the same as in the js example above. (It uses the firebase (client) library. My understanding is that the firebase-admin library does not allow anonymous signin.)

```
const firebase=require('firebase');

  var config = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log(error.message);
  });

let db = firebase.firestore();

db.collection('collection').get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

The following error is triggered when *db.collection('collection').get()* is called. (earlier anonymous signing goes through)

```
Error getting documents { FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (/root/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1201:28)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (/root/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:19708:16)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (/root/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:19955:44)
    at PersistentListenStream.onMessage (/root/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:16828:43)
    at /root/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:16757:30
    at /root/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:16797:28
    at /root/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js:17844:20
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  code: 'permission-denied',
  name: 'FirebaseError',
  toString: [Function] }
```

Thanks again for any pointers!

Comment: Security rules are rejecting the query.

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your Firestore rules?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the rules for this one, as I am working with a 3rd party firebase account. Whatever the rules are, they should apply to both versions of the library in the same way. Why the inconsistency? There appears to be a fundamental difference in the way the library works on JS and Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that you are actually not signed-in when you fetch Firestore. As a matter of fact the [`signInAnonymously()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#signinanonymously) method **is asynchronous** and you don't wait that the Promise returned by this method resolves before fetching Firestore.

So, the following may solve your problem:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
let db = firebase.firestore();

firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
.then(cred => {
    return db.collection('collection').get()
})
.then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

Note that you should do the same in the JavaScript SDK version:

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
.then(cred => {
  foo();
}}
.catch(function(error) {
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

Comment: Very interesting point. It could be that internally js and node handle some asynchronous calls differently and you only get a promis in node, while js returns an object. Let me check and come back in a bit.

Comment: Thanks Renaud. So it wasn't a firebase library issue, just specific to the way node async stuff works.